# Convert a date vector to ranks

Tags: r, date, rank

I have the the date vector:

```
d <- c("30/5/15", "6/6/15", "23/5/15")
```

I would like to convert it to `2, 3, 1` with smallest rank to older and biggest to newest.

I tried `rank(d)` but it looks like it makes the ranking based on days only and reverse, it returns `3, 1, 2`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convert to `Date` class, then `numeric`, then `rank`:

```
d <- c("30/5/15", "6/6/15", "23/5/15")

rank(as.numeric(as.Date(d, "%d/%m/%y")))

#[1] 2 3 1
```

Suggestions from comments:

- drop `as.numeric`, as *rank* can handle dates. Although it might be preferable to be explicit.
- use lubridate package: `library(lubridate); rank(dmy(d))`

Comment: Or `library(lubridate); rank(dmy(d))`

Comment: @akrun that was my original solution, then decided not to depend on an extra package for a simple task.

Answer (score 0):

convert the data into date format and then rank it. internally date will save in numeric values. so it can rank on it.

```
d <- c("30/5/15", "6/6/15", "23/5/15")
rank(as.Date(d,'%d/%m/%y'))
```